# How to Set a Fixed Width for a Div Element with Display Inline?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have the below div element:

```
<div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; display: inline;">
                Hello my friend, How are you?</div>
```

The width is always ignored! how could I have it as 40px?

Thanks,

Answer (score 24):

Use `display:inline-block;`. Size properties are ignored at most elements with `display:inline`.

```
<div style="width: 40px; height: 40px; overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;">
            Hello my friend, How are you?</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? The answer is correct, as seen at http://jsfiddle.net/bd8YE/

Comment: "inline-block" might not be recognized by all browsers as I recall it, but the answer is correct; you can not set a width with "display:inline", you have to change it to something else.

Comment: @janzi Display-block is supported by all decent browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Comment: apparently I was remembering IE7 issues.