# How to build a constant width div?

Tags: html, css

In this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/6/

I have a table ( or matrix have you ) of bookmarks.  Each row is labeled with a tag.  I need this column to have a constant width.

The class ( or column ) that needs the constant width is

```
.tag_hold
```

I tried the obvious of

```
width: 100px:
```

but this had no observable effect.

Comment: display: inline-block, http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/9/

Comment: use a `<table>` here!

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting Saying I don't use tables as a personal choice is like saying, "I don't use vowels." It's not a matter of your personal choice, its a matter of standards.

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting It's not a matter of it "not hindering you," it's a matter of your adherence to community standards. When you choose to ignore standards you are writing code which is not maintainable. This diminishes the value of your application and your perceived value by future employers. Here is a great article on [when and why to use tables and not divs](http://www.noupe.com/how-tos/better-ui-design-proper-use-of-tables.html). The best thing is that you actually say, "I have a table."

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting One more comment. Your image tags are missing the slash. They should be `<img src=""/>`

Comment: @screenmutt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Comment: This is an HTML 5 doc - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

Comment: @isherwood I recant. I forgot they weren't required anymore. However, a lot of editors will base syntax highlighting on them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Set a Fixed Width for a Div Element with Display Inline?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262459/how-to-set-a-fixed-width-for-a-div-element-with-display-inline)

Comment: @nativist.bill.cutting [Divs vs Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637629/divs-vs-tables-for-tabular-data)

Comment: True. Fiddle among them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a width on an inline element, so that's why the width doesn't have any effect. Try `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`.

That said, if this is for tabular data, that's exactly what `<table>` is for – no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Exactly. Rigid "personal deprecation" of tables is not a wise approach.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why is isn't working is because display is `inline` when it should be `inline-block`

http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/11/

Answer (score 1):

Change the `display: inline;` for `display: inline-block;`

```
.tag_hold{
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline` makes the browser ignore the width and push the element regardless. What you would have to do is `display:block` or `display:inline-block` and float the elements depending on the look you want.

or use Twitter Bootstrap...

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say you should use `inline-block`

I took the time to clean up your css a bit as it has some unnecessary css 
http://jsfiddle.net/sjD24/12/