# Width of inline div ignored in jQuery

Tags: jquery, width, html-lists

I am trying to have a list with lines in the format of "A description1", "BB description2", "C description3", and have them all align. I have a ul,li list and tried to make the "A" or "BB" or "C" section have a fixed length through CSS, but that is not working. Here is my code

```
$("#list").append("<ul></ul").css({liststyle: "none"});
  for(i=0;i<myArray1.length;i++)
    $("#list")
    .append($('<li>')
      .append("<div>").css({display: "inline", width: "20px", background: "red"})
      .append(myArray2[i].toUpperCase()+" ")
      .append("</div>")
      .append($("<a>", {
         href: (num=myArray1[i].indexOf("|"))==-1 ? "/"+myArray1[i].toLowerCase()
                                                  : myArray1[i].substr(num+1) ,
         html: num==-1 ? myArray1[i] : myArray1[i].substr(0,num)
      })
    .css({color: "#9999FF"} )
    )
   .append("<br>")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Inline` `divs`aren't affected by the `width` css attribute.

A simple Google search should have answered that question.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262459/how-to-set-a-fixed-width-for-a-div-element-with-display-inline) is a question asking "How to Set a Fixed Width for a Div Element with Display Inline?"